# TextBlock Text-Binding from ListView items

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How can I change the Text of a TextBlock when the selection in my ListView changes?
I don't want do this manually...
All Items of the ListView are LogEntry's (class)... Can I use Binding in the Text-Attribute of the TextBlock to get a specific property of the selected Item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact there are multiple solutions, i give you the most "WPF" like answer, but imo also the least flexible.

First you need to set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Now if you select an item, the bound [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) will set the item as the CurrentItem.

Now your TextBox/Block can bind to this specific item via a special binding syntax using a '/'.
For Example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LogEntries/}"/>
```

of course you can get a specific property from the current item via binding aswell

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LogEntries/WarningMessage}"/>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But the TextBox-Text has to update when the selection of the listView changes... So I need the specific item of the listView and for every TextBox a specific property (DependencyProperty) of the LogEntry-Item...

Comment: Don't worry, it does. When you bind a collection to a ItemsControl, WPF will not bind it directly instead a CollectionView is bound between the control and your collection. With IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem the collectionview will keep track of your selected item. Binding to your Collection, makes the binding aware of the CollectionView, so every control binding to your collection, also has access to the currentitem.

Comment: @LucaNateMahler please remember to accept an answer, to give proper credit.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a listview like this:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding LogEntries}" Name="logs" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">


</ListView>


<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=logs, Path=SelectedItem}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource logTemplate}"/>
```

Now you need to provide that logTemplate in the Resources.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogEntry}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LogText}"/>  <-- This is a Property-Binding of your custom class
   </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The last thing missing is to provide the namespace to your local class LogEntry. If you use an awesome tool like Resharper, it will insert the namespace for you. Otherwise, here a sample declaration:

```
<UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.App.Namespace.LogEntry;assembly=My.App"
 ... (rest of namespace declarations)
```

Comment: Yes, ItemsSource is correct.
Internally I work with a ObservableCollection<LogEntry> and LogEntry is a subclass of DependencyObject...

Comment: ok, it seems you need to read an article or a book on wpf, but to answer your questions: a contentcontrol can display any kind of element and when you give it a contenttemplate, it will style it according to that template. the DataTemplate on the other hand, is a (as the name says) template, that works for a certain data type (LogEntry in your case) and contains Elements that bind to properties of that Type. There are lots of good beginner articles on the subject. google is your friend.